# How to keep your model in sync with an {{#each}} block?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have something like this:

```
Template.todoList.helpers({
    todos: function() {
        return Todos.find({}); // Returns records with a todoText, ownerId and done field.
    }
});
```

And then in the template I use a `{{#each}}` block to list the todos. But I want to be able to change if they are `done` with a checkbox. If I just add a checkbox like this in the `{{#each}}` block, it will correctly display the initial state, but if I toggle the checkbox, the record will not update. I would need to keep track of the `_id` of the record, but where would I store it? If I can get hold of the correct `_id` the rest is very simple:

```
Template.todoList.events({
    'change .doneCheckbox': function(event) {
        var todoId = ??;
        Todos.update(todoId, {$set: {done:event.target.checked}}); 
    }
});
```

What would I insert at the place of `??`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be available from `this` (more specifically `this._id`):

```
var todo = this,
    todoID = todo._id;
```

You can access other properties from the record too (e.g. `this.done`).